# TIBCO Spotfire datepicker function error in 12.5.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I recently upgraded from spotfire 10 to 12.5.0 where I was using a function **datepicker** and now when I open my DXP I get the following error after upgrading to spotfire 12.5.0 -

```
Execution of Javascript failed:
Type: TypeError
Message: $(...).datepicker is not a function
Stacktrace: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I use the following JS Scirpt : -

```
//update document property after selection
function datePicker_onSelect(selectedDate){
 //alert(selectedDate)
 $("#dt1 input").focus()
 $("#dt1 input").blur()
}

//jquery datepicker configuration
//you can comment the buttonImageOnly and buttonImage lines to show a button instead of a calendar or the image of your choice.
pickerOptions = {
 showOn: 'button', 
 buttonImageOnly: true, 
 buttonImage: 'http://staff.washington.edu/tabrooks/343INFO/UnobtrusiveDatePicker/cal-grey.gif', 
 minDate: "-15M", maxDate: "-1D",
 defaultDate: -1,
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 altField:"#dt1 input",
 onSelect:datePicker_onSelect
 }

//create the date picker
document.getElementById('dt1picker').innerHTML="<input type='hidden' id='datePicker'>"
$("#datePicker").datepicker(pickerOptions);
```

I Tired surfing on for similar issues and found it is that TIBCO has discontinued supporting third party libraries. Scripts that have been relying on the jQuery library previously distributed with Spotfire will now fail, as attempting to use the $ selector/jQuery alias will result in errors like the above. Any fixes to this or any resoltions which directly are available in spotfire 12.5.0?
Thanks